# In Excel how do I create a condensed list from another array?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long list of keywords in the A column. I am trying to search that column for cells that contain a specific word. I then want to display all cells that contain that word in a new column. 
For instance, if I want to search cells that contain "dog" anywhere within a cell between the range of A1:A2000 and then populate cells in the C column with the values of the cells that contained the word "dog" in it. In effect creating a new list

Thank you.

Comment: quickest way is pivot table, did you considered it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place in cell "C1" and copy down. Be sure and enter the formula with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$2000,SMALL(IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("dog",$A$1:$A$2000),ROW($A$1:$A$2000)-ROW($A$1)+1),FALSE),ROWS($C$1:C1))),"")
```

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by enter the formula withy ctrl+shift+enter?

Comment: Normally after you place a formula in the formula bar, you just press Enter. With this formula though and other array formulas, you need to instead hold down CTRL + SHIFT and press Enter. Doing so will give you a different result, and in this case, the correct result. If you need further clarification, you can come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85263/excel-talk and I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formular in C1 cell:

IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,"dog")), A1, "")

Hope this can help